# Prove $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \le \limsup_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume that $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers.

Prove that :
$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \le \limsup_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^{\frac{1}{k}} \le \limsup_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$

Note : I have no clue. It seems like we don't know anything about the sequence. How could we prove part (a)? Since I don't have a clear image of part (a), I can't give the example of part (b) too!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ r = \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}a_{k+1}/a_k$. Let $r \neq \infty$. For any $r_0 >r $ then there is an $N$ such that $k \geq N$ implies $a_{k+1}/a_k \leq r_0$ since sup sequnce is a decresing sequence. Fix $j \in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that
$$ a_{N+j} \leq a_{N+j-2}r_0^2 \leq....\leq a_Nr_0^j$$
i.e $ a_k \leq a_N r_0^{k-N} \forall k \geq N$. In particular, if $n > N$ then
 $$ \sup_{k \geq n}a_k^{1/k} \leq (a_Nr_0^{-N})^{1/k}.r_0 $$
Taking limit of the above inequality we have $\sup_{k \rightarrow \infty}a_k^{1/k} \leq r_0$ and as $r_0 \downarrow r$ we have the desired result for rightmost inequality. Similarly leftmost will also follow